# XAMPP on OS X: PHP can't create files because of permissions, but it should run as root

Tags: macos, php, file-permissions, root, xampp

I run XAMPP (which starts PHP and apache) with this command:

```
do shell script "sudo xampp start" password "******" with administrator privileges
```

So I asume it has admin privileges, does PHP get those in a kind of cascading effect?
Because PHP can't create files where there aren't 'other' write permission, but I, as root, can, so if PHP was running as root should be able too.

Is there a way I can check if PHP is running as root, and if not, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All webservers switch to a restricted account (`nobody`, `httpd`, `www-data`) as soon as it can - usually just after binding to TCP ports and reading SSL keys. It cannot go back up. PHP-CGI *never* gains admin privileges.

Besides, **who in their right mind would give root to a web page?** Current attacks are already bad enough.

Comment: Yeah, sounds right.